# windows multiple monitors setup script with python

Tags: python

i have 3 monitors i use for work etc and i have one TV4k connected with hdmi witch i dont use exept when am gonna watch a movie or series for my computer.
so what i do when i want to watch the TV i right click on my desktop and go to display settings and disconects 2 of my secendary monitors since my gpu has problem with 3 108p + 4k at the same time.
so i have one setup with monitor 3,1,4, diconnect 2

and another setup with 3/2, diconnected 4,1

3 is my main display.

so i want to make a script pref in python that change my monitor setup from a_work to b_movietime.

Comment: i was thinkig of using python lisen to ... i dont know, maybe  "right click on desktop, open desktop setup"

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, use [multi_monitor_tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html). It provides cli so you can wrap it with python code that will run `subprocess` calls :)